# Javascript onclick custom table sorting

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript. Here is my question.

I have a table with the rows.

Name Bytes

1. A    35.06G
2. B 67.09G
3. C -17.05G
4. D    78.96M

I am getting the values as strings from the backend python.
I am using Django python in the background.

I want sort the table based on the values on clicking the header (Bytes) in the table. I want to write custom sort function, where i convert gigabytes,megabytes to bytes and sort them and not to use the "sortable" function.

Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

this might help, or I might be missing?

```
function headerSort() {
            var $r = $("#header").val();
            $r.CustomSorting(function(a, b) {
                if (a.text < b.text) return -1;
                if (a.text == b.text) return 0;
                return 1;
            });
            $($r).remove();
            $("#myDiv").append($($r));
            }



    $r.CustomSorting(function(a, b) {
                   return a.value-b.value;
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as an array, you sort them like this:

```
var table = [ {name:"A", bytes:"35.06G"}, ... ];
table.sort(function(a,b) { return un_SI_number(a.bytes)-un_SI_number(b.bytes); });
```

As a html table, you could use jQuery.fn.sortElements

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

### [Solution](http://jsbin.com/vixot/1/edit) with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

#### html

```
<button id="sortTable">Sort</button>
<table class="sort">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th><th>Unit</th></tr>
  <tr><td>A</td><td>35.06</td><td>G</td></tr>
  <tr><td>B</td><td>67.09</td><td>G</td></tr>
  <tr><td>C</td><td>17.05</td><td>G</td></tr>
  <tr><td>D</td><td>78.96</td><td>M</td></tr>
  <tr><td>E</td><td>55.06</td><td>M</td></tr>
</table>
```

#### js

```
$(function(){
  var units = {
    'T': 10E12,
    'G': 10E9,
    'M': 10E6
  };
  $('#sortTable').click(function(){
    var data = [];
    $('table.sort tr').each(function(i,tr){
      if(i && tr){
        var value = parseFloat($(tr.children[1]).text());
        var unit = $(tr.children[2]).text();
        data.push({
          html: $(tr).html(),
          value: value * units[unit]
        });
      }
    });
    data.sort(function(a,b){
      return b.value - a.value;
    });
    $('table.sort tr').each(function(i,tr){
      if(i && tr){
        var item = data[i - 1];
        $(tr).html(item.html);
      }
    });
  });
});
```